# In most geometry courses, we learn that there's no such thing as "SSA Congruence".

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In most geometry courses, we learn that there's no such thing as "SSA Congruence". That is, if we have triangles $ABC$ and $DEF$ such that $AB = DE$, $BC = EF$, and $\angle A = \angle D$, then we cannot deduce that $ABC$ and $DEF$ are congruent.

However, there are a few special cases in which SSA "works". That is, suppose $ABC$ is a triangle. Let $AB = x$, $BC = y$, and $\angle A = \theta$. For some values of $x$, $y$, and $\theta$, we can uniquely determine the third side, $AC$.

(a) Use the Law of Cosines to derive a quadratic equation in $AC$.

(b) Use the quadratic polynomial you found in part (a) in order to find conditions on $x, y,$ and $\theta$ which guarantee that the side $AC$ is uniquely determined.

Comment: Can you do part a? Hint: the angle chosen should be $\theta$, which tells you how the three sides should enter the problem.

Comment: I don't see a question here.  Are you asking whether your procedure is correct?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

The first figure depicts the case when $\angle A$, $AB$, and $BC=BC'$, do not determine one single triangle.

[image]

However, when $\angle C =\frac{\pi}{2}$ then $\angle A$, $AB$, and $BC$ do determine one single triangle.

[image]